In what sense is $q(\eta,\eta_x)$ the rate at which $\eta$ changes to $\eta_x$? (spin systems)
Let $S$ be a finite set and $E=\{0,1\}^S$. For $\eta\in E$ and $x\in S$, let $\eta_x\in E$ be the configuration obtained from $\eta$ by "flipping" the coordinate $x$, leaving the other coordinates unchanged. Now let $Q$ be a $Q$-matrix such that $q(\eta,\eta')=0$ if $\eta$ and $\eta'$ differ in more than one coordinate. Then

the interpretation of $q(\eta,\eta_x)$ is that it gives the rate at which $\eta$ changes to $\eta_x$

(see section 4.2 in Liggett's introduction to Continuous time
Markov Processes). What exactly does Liggett mean? As far as I know the law of the first transition time $\tau$ (for the process started in $\eta$) doesn't change if we condition on $\eta(\tau)=\eta_x$. So my second thought was that the first hitting time of $\eta_x$ for the process started in $\eta$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $q(\eta,\eta_x)$, but I dont see any evidence for this. Can someone elaborate please?


Theorem:
If $T_1,\ldots,T_n$ are independent random variables and $T_i\sim
> \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_i)$, then \begin{equation*}
 M:=\min(T_1,\ldots,T_n)\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda) \end{equation*}
with $\lambda:=\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_n$ and \begin{equation*}
      \mathbb P(M=T_i)=\lambda_i/\lambda. \end{equation*}

That being said, note that
$$c(\eta)=\sum_xq(\eta,\eta_x)$$
and$$p(\eta,\eta_x)=q(\eta,\eta_x)/c(\eta).$$
That is, the process started in $\eta$ behaves (up to and including the first transition) as if each site $x$ flipped after an exponential time with paramter $q(\eta,\eta_x)$.
I hope that some expert can confirm this.
